# CoreData unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, swift2

Having an app where I type username, pick a picture from imagePickerController and all that data is saved to core data and retrieved to tableview cell and is working fine, however if I don't choose picture app is crashing with log "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value", I forgot how to do that, can't remember in what project I solved that.

```
let imageData = NSData(data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photoImageView.image!, 1.0)!)
newUser.setValue(imageData, forKey: "image")
```

Something like if image data != nil {
} ??

Comment: You *have* to read this: [Swift Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330) (Apple documentation).

Answer (score 2):

Try `if let image = photoImageView.image {//use the image}`. This will unwrap the optional in a safe way.

Be careful when you use the `!` operator, you are basically guaranteeing the thing will never be nil. Use the `if let` statement or `?` operator unless there is absolutely no way that the variable in question could be nil.

Answer (score -2):

solved with this

```
if photoImageView == nil {
        let imageData = NSData(data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photoImageView.image!, 1.0)!)
        newUser.setValue(imageData, forKey: "image")
    }
```

Comment: `if photoImageView == nil` then `photoImageView.image!` **will** crash, the same way it already does. You should read the answers and links you get to your questions, if you really want to learn. And in any case you should check that the code you post as an answer actually works.

Comment: My answer is "read the link I've provided in the comments to your question", it contains your answers.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: that code is working (almost), now i can proceed to tableview with typing only in textfield, no crashing now, and when i go back to choose a picture and click save i again got no picture. Somehow i need to use if statement to say if photo is not picked, proceed only with textfield, but i can't do that because i dont know yet, last 7 days i'm into core data, and i'm a little overwhelmed to remember how i manage to even save textfield and image and load into tableview with core data. PLs help with that if statement, so if photo is not picked proceed to tableview when save is clicked, thank you.